# Statistics random variables uniformly distributed

Tags: probability

Let $U_1,U_2$ be two uniformly distributed independent random variables. Show that $X_1=cos (2\pi U_1)\sqrt{-2 \log(U_2)},\: X_2=sin (2\pi U_1)\sqrt{-2 \log(U_2)}$ are normally distributed independent random variables.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110168/proof-of-the-box-muller-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_{1}^{2} + Y_{1}^{2} = -2\log(U_{2}) \Rightarrow U_{2} = \exp(\frac{-1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2))$

$U_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}(\frac{X_2}{X_1})$

Now using the change of variables formula for PDF i.e.

$f_{Y}(y) = |det(J)| \times f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))$

where $J$ is the Jacobian of $x$ wrt $y$.

In our case, $J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial U_1}{\partial X_1} & \frac{\partial U_1}{\partial X_2}\\ 
\frac{\partial U_2}{\partial X_1} & \frac{\partial U_2}{\partial X_2}
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1}{2\pi}(\frac{X_2}{X_1^2+X_2^2}) & \frac{1}{2\pi}(\frac{X_1}{X_1^2+X_2^2})\\ 
X_1\exp(\frac{-1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2)) & X_2\exp(\frac{-1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2))
\end{bmatrix} $

Thererfore, $|det(J)| = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(\frac{-1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2))$

Finally, $f_X(g^{-1}(y)) = f_{U_1,U_2}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}(\frac{X_2}{X_1}), \exp(\frac{-1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2))) = 1\times1 = 1$, because both the input variables will always be in $[0,1]$ (from first two equations) and hence the independent uniform distributions will have corresponding PDFs of 1.

Finally, $f_{X_1,X_2}(X_1,X_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(\frac{-1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2))$ which is the distribution of 2 independent normal random variables.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot!