# Probability theory: showing independence between two r.v. and their distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence, change-of-variable

This question concerns elementary problem solving in proability theory. I have two random variables

$$
\begin{align}
X_{1}&=\sqrt{-2\ln{(U_{1})}}\cos{(2\pi U_{2})}\\
X_{2}&=\sqrt{-2\ln{(U_{1}})}\sin{(2\pi U_{2})}
\end{align}
$$

where $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables in the unit interval. I would like to show that both $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are $N(0,1)$-distributed and independent. I have made an attempt and my solution so far is that the inversion of the transformation is given by

$$
\begin{align}
X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}&=-2\ln{(U_{1})}[\cos^{2}{(2\pi U_{2})}+\sin^{2}{(2\pi U_{2})}]=-2\ln{(U_{1})}\implies U_{1}=\exp{\left(-\frac{X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)},\\
\frac{X_{2}}{X_{1}}&=\frac{\sqrt{-2\ln{(U_{1}})}\sin{(2\pi U_{2})}}{\sqrt{-2\ln{(U_{1})}}\cos{(2\pi U_{2})}}=\tan{(2\pi U_{2})} \implies U_{2}=\frac{\arctan{(X_{2}/X_{1})}}{2\pi}.
\end{align}
$$

Now, in order to finally obtain the distribution of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ I need to use the *transformation theorem*, hence I need the Jacobian,

$$
\mathbf{J}(x_{1},x_{2}) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}h_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}h_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}h_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}h_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $h_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})=\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)}$ and $h_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})=\frac{\arctan{(x_{2}/x_{1})}}{2\pi}$. I obtain the partial derivatives

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}h_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})&=-x_{1}\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)},& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}h_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})&=-x_{2}\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)},\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}h_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)^{2}}\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}^{2}},& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}h_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)^{2}}\frac{1}{x_{1}}.
\end{align}
$$

The determinant of $\mathbf{J}$ thus becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\det{(\mathbf{J}(x_{1},x_{2}))} &= -\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)^{2}}\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)^{2}\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)}.
\end{align}
$$

The joint density of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ is

$$
\begin{align}
f_{X_{1},X_{2}}(x_{1},x_{2}) &= f_{U_{1},U_{2}}(h_{1},h_{2})\cdot\vert\det{(\mathbf{J})}\vert=\{\text{Independence}\}=1^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp{\left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{1\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{e}^{{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_{1}-0}{1}\right)^{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{1\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{e}^{{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_{2}-0}{1}\right)^{2}}}.
\end{align}
$$

Since the joint density factorizes into two univariate normal distributions this implies that $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent and $\sim N(0,1)$.

Note: I believe I happened to solve the problem I was stuck on while writing it all out. If anyone sees anyhting wrong with this solution let me know.

Comment: FYI, this is called the *Box-Muller transform*.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1110168/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3548713/321264 should help to verify.