# Are functions of two independent random variables also independent?

Tags: random-variables, independence

We have two independent random variables:

```
1. r ~ U(0,1)
2. θ ~ U(0,2π)
```

Also we have X = r.cosθ and Y = r.sinθ.

Are X and Y independent?

Comment: [Box-Muller-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). The answer to the isolated  question in your title is however ***no***.

Comment: A clarification: the [Box-Muller method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110168/proof-of-the-box-muller-method) says that \begin{align}X&=\sqrt{-2\ln U}\cos(2\pi V)\\Y&=\sqrt{-2\ln U}\sin(2\pi V)\end{align} are independent and standard normal when $U,V\sim U(0,1)$ and independent. Your case is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

A simple argument for 'no' is: $P(X > 2^{-\frac{1}{2}}) = P(Y > 2^{-\frac{1}{2}}) > 0$, but $P(X > 2^{-\frac{1}{2}} \mbox{ and } Y > 2^{-\frac{1}{2}}) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you know for example that $X \ge 0.8$, then you now also know that $|Y| \le 0.6$, because $X^2+Y^2=r^2 \le 1$. That means you get information about $Y$ from $X$ that you didn't have before (only $|Y| \le 1$ is known from the original formula).

Comment: This reasoning is so convincing that I am at the moment really wondering why the Box-Muller-method works. I know it does. Ah: I now why. In OP's case $X^2+Y^2=r^2\le 1$ in the Box-Muller case this is not true. +1 for that answer.

Comment: Right. The $\ln U$ part makes the radius unbounded in Box-Muller (which I didn't know before).